# Count number of characters after specific character in textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation

using winforms / vb.net

I am trying to count how many characters exist in "textbox3" after a specific character "." in a textbox.

examples:

2adf      = 0  (no "." exists)

2adf.     = 0

2adf.2    = 1

2adf.2a   = 2

2adf.2af  = 3

2adf.2afe = 4

I already have a function to search if there is a "."

```
if (CountCharacter(TextBox3.Text, ".") = 1) then
    'a "." exists so count number of characters after "."

end if

Public Function CountCharacter(ByVal value As String, ByVal ch As Char) As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer = 0
    For Each c As Char In value
        If c = ch Then cnt += 1
    Next
    Return cnt
End Function
```

I am not sure how to check the count after the "." though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [string.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for this task

```
Sub Main
    Dim test = "2adf.2afe"
    Dim result = CountCharsAfter(test, "."c)
    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub

Public Function CountCharsAfter(input as string, charToSearch as Char) as Integer
    DIm pos = input.LastIndexOf(charToSearch)
    if pos = -1 then
       return 0
    else
        return input.Length - (pos + 1)
    End if
End Function
```

Comment: Rethinking at the question. Perhaps the best method is LastIndexOf

Comment: both appear to function properly

Comment: Well, if there is just one "." both works in the same manner. The results are different if there are more than one ".", that's the reason of my comment. It depends on your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    Dim NoChar As Integer = CalculateChra("12adf.2afe", ".")

Private Function CalculateChra(ByVal V_String As String, ByVal LastChar As Char) As Integer

    Dim Start As String = Split(V_String, LastChar)(0) & "."
    Dim M As String = V_String.Substring(Start.Length)
    Return M.Length
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim n,cnt as integer
n=0
cnt=0
   Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
            If e.KeyChar = Chr(46) Then
                n = Len(TextBox1.Text)
            End If
            If n <> 0 Then
                cnt += 1
            End If
            MsgBox(" no.of charectors after '.' is/are : " & cnt - 1)
        End Sub
```